# EXCEL VBA Choose a file and search the first row for key words then copy the column to another file

Tags: excel, vba, search, copy-paste

I have the following issue.

I want to choose a folder with multiple .xlsx files in it.
Loop through the files and open them.
The search the first row for KEYWORDS and if one of those keywords is found.
COPY the entire Column full of data to the sheet with the keyowrd as the Name of the sheet and the first Column of every data. 
`ThisWorkbook.Sheet("KEYWORD")`

I have the following code, but it is getting complicated for me as an absolute beginner with coding in general.

```
Sub FINDandCopy()

With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With


    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim NewSh As Worksheet
    Dim SHINDEX As String


File = Application.GetOpenFilename
File_Name = Dir(File)

Workbooks.Open Filename:=File


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

       .Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = File_Name

End With

    'MyArr = Array("Banana")
    MyArr = Array("I51", "I54", "I55", "I57", "I58")

   Range("A:A").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(File_Name).Range("A:A")

    With Worksheets(1).Rows(1)

        Rcount = 0

        For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

                FirstAddress = Rng.Address

                Do

                    Rcount = Rcount + 1
                    Range(Rng, Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlDown)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(File_Name).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)


                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With

Workbooks(2).Close
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

My Keywords are found in the Array (I51, ....) and these are part of the header f.e. (I51.RhValue).

The last error has been changed:

From:

`Range(Rng, Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp))`

to

`Range(Rng, Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlDown))`

SOLVED Thanks to SJR!

Thank you Daniel!

Comment: Are the items in your array found more than once in the header row? You are searching A1:A100 though, not the first row?

Comment: Yes they are found multiple Times in each First row

Comment: Does the above code do something? `After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count)` will make `Find` to search after the last cell in the range, not inside it...

Comment: So why are you searching A1:A100? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: @FaneDuru - that just means it will start searching in the first cell of the range rather than missing it.

Comment: Thank you #SJR Iam going to edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give this a try. I assume you want the results pasted across the sheet (in columns) rathen than down (by rows).

You were pretty much there, just need to copy the whole column when the header is found.

```
Sub FINDandCopy()

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim NewSh As Worksheet

strDatei = Application.GetOpenFilename

If strDatei <> False Then

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

MyArr = Array("I51", "I54", "I55", "I57", "I58")

With Sheets(1).Rows(1) 'shoud add a workbook reference as working with more than one file
    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                Range(Rng, Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyArr(I)).Cells(1, columns.Count).end(xltoleft).offset(,1)
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.
I posted a picture with an example file and i hope this clears things up.

But one thing:

```Range(Rng, Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1,Rcount) 'assuming you want to copy across by column```

I want to copy this to ThisWorkbook.Sheets(KEYWORD)
How does this work

Comment: So you mean if you find "I51" you want it copied to the sheet called that? I've amended the code.

Comment: Thank you!!!
The Problem is the search function can't find the Banana term in the first row.
AND: Where can i learn the way you declared that path because for me that's really difficult.
Is there somewhere a guide i didnt find ?

Comment: Do you mean it's not there or it doesn't find it?

Comment: the first column gets copied!
and the first row of the found names, but the data below the first row is lost

Comment: I just spotted a couple of errors in the code - had you corrected? Otherwise you would have got error messages. It works for me so not sure, you will have to do some checking yourself. Perhaps post a screenshot of your data as I don't know what it looks like.

Comment: I posted the code that i am using right now and a picture of the problem i am still having.
Maybe it is a Problem with the

 rng.column

in the code.